# How do I find out which module handle a GET/POST/PUT?

Tags: 7, ajax

I'm reading a Drupal 7 project. However, unfortunately I can't find out which module handle an Ajax request.
I only know the destination address which has been rewritten. (Suppose it's http://example.com/abc)

So, the problem is how could I find out which module handle my Ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

### Menu items (in code)

Drupal module register endpoint with `hook_menu()`. You can search the endpoint within the project, such as `abc`. It should stay inside `hook_menu()` with type `MENU_CALLBACK`.

You may find something like below.

```php
function mymodule_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['abc'] = array(
     'title' => 'Ajax endpoint',
     'page callback' => 'mymodule_ajax_callback',
     ...
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
   ),
   return $items();
}
```

### Menu items (in database)

In database, table `menu_router` saved all registered menu items. You can lookup the endpoint on `path` column and find the corresponding callback function on `page_callback` column.

### Modules

There is a number of module which provide UI or APIs for developer creating endpoints. Such as [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) and [RESTful Web Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/restws).

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: I have added an example of hook_menu().

Comment: I mean if we send a JSON `data:"{'value':10}"`. How can we get `data` in Drupal 7?

Comment: use `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: No. I mean, where should I put it in? Should I put it in a specifics function?

Comment: If you have a new question please ask it separately @ZhipengYANG, comments are just for getting clarification on the current question/answer

Comment: OK. But actually you didn't answer my question. I need to debug an Ajax request. But I didn't find out which module is correspondant to that request. I only know the Ajax request is sent to an address like this: http://example.com/page1/id.

Comment: @ZhipengYANG did you search the uri 'page1/id' in your whole project? You can search a keyword in whold project easily with SublimeText. If you don't know how to make it. Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519040/search-in-all-files-in-a-project-in-sublime-text-3)

Comment: The id in `/page1/id` is a variable as well as page1 is too common that I can't figure out.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check the section **Menu items (in database)**